# Angular 2 how to iterate through multi-dimensional arrays?

Tags: arrays, angular

***EDIT#2***

Unfortunately, I haven't had any success incorporating either one of these suggestions. It's late, so I'm heading off to bed, but I'll try to update tomorrow.

### Thanks to Pradeep Jain for the help. I'll also try out the Pipe that evil mind suggested.

I've learned how to use the *ngFor command, but it looks like it only works with simple arrays. Here's the code I'm trying to iterate through.

```
import {Lesson} from './lesson';

export var LESSONS: Lesson[] = [
{
    "idL": 1,
    "subject": 'Chapter One',
    "points": [
                'picture story', 'spelling test', 'words'
            ]
},
{
    "idL": 2,
    "subject": 'Words',
    "points": [
            'words', 'bacon', 'proliferation'
    ]
}
]
```

So I am trying to access that second array called "points". I don't think it's improperly formatted, but I haven't been able to figure out how to access it.

I did read about angularJs's foreach command, but Angular2's documentation does not show such a command is available.

Any advice?

Answer (score 11):

**Update (2.0.0)**

```
<table>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let lesson of LESSONS; let i = index">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let point of lesson.points; let j = index">
        <tr>{{point}}</tr>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
```

`<ng-container>` is a helper element that is not stamped to the DOM. It allows to use the same syntax as inline `*ngIf` and `*ngFor`

**Original**

Try this one:

```
<table>
<template ngFor #lesson [ngForOf]="LESSONS" #i="index">
  <template ngFor #point [ngForOf]="lesson.points" #j="index">
  <tr>{{point}}</tr>
  </template>
</template>
```

Working example <kbd>[Working Plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/Zzuqt3UNj2bKYWz46Tnp?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Oh wow, this helps a lot. Thanks mate!

Can you point me in the direction to learn more about [ngForOf]?

Comment: your welcome @Nathan , the only best article i have found so far https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/NgFor-directive.html

Comment: also according to me why to use extra pipe when default `[ngForOf]` gives us the same functionality is't it @Nathan @evilmin

Comment: I'm actually having a pretty hard time incorporating either one of these two suggestions. With yours, I do not have the template in the main app.component file, but rather in their own components. 

As far as I can tell, it should work, but doesn't show any data, despite everything routing correctly, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me in Angular 4, using Pardeep Jain's answer as a basis. Almost the same as StepUps answer, but with ng-containers:

```
 constructor() {

        this.data = {  
            displayArray:[
                ["Top Row 1st col", "Top Row 2nd col", "Top Row 3rd col"],
                ["Middle Row 1st col", "Middle Row 2nd col", "Middle Row 3rd col"],
                ["Bottom Row 1st col", "Bottom Row 2nd col", "Bottom Row 3rd col"]
            ]
        }

    };
```

in the template:

```
<table >
    <ng-container *ngFor="let row of data.displayArray; let i = index">
        <tr>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let col of row; let j = index">
                <td>{{col}}</td>
            </ng-container>
        </tr> 
    </ng-container>
</table>
```

I didn't need the indexes, but I left them in in case they are needed by others.

Answer (score 1):

try to use this pipe

```
@Pipe({ name: 'values',  pure: false })
export class ValuesPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, args: any[] = null): any {
    return Object.keys(value).map(key => value[key]);
  }
}

<div *ng-for="#value of object | values"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, you have the following multidimensional array:

**TypeScript:**

```
export class AppComponent {
  rows: any[] = [];      

  constructor() {     
    this.rows = this.multiArray;        
  }

  multiArray = [
    //row 1
    [
      {cellValue:'row1 col1', cellId: 1},
      {cellValue:'row1 col2', cellId: 1},
    ],
    //row 2
    [
      {cellValue:'row2 col1', cellId: 2},
      {cellValue:'row2 col2', cellId: 1}      
    ],
    //row 3
    [
      {cellValue:'row3 col1', cellId: 3},
      {cellValue:'row3 col2', cellId: 1}      
    ]
  ]
}
```

And you can loop through array like this:

**HTML:**

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let row of rows; let i = index">    
    <td *ngFor="let cell of row; let i = index">        
          <b>{{ cell.cellValue }} editable</b>        
    </td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```