# Angular 2 page not iterating through array

Tags: arrays, angular

**EDIT**

Figured out the problem. It ended up being a promise that I had written and it was interfering with a similar promise. After deleting it, it's not posting to the page.

I still have to figure out how to read multi-dimentional arrays, but I'm glad I was able to figure this bug out on my own.

我想用頭中桌子

First, I want to show you this: [iterating through multi arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37089581/angular-2-how-to-iterate-through-multi-dimensional-arrays)

Here, I asked how to iterate through multi-dimensional arrays with Angular 2. Two guys gave me possible answers, but I believe i may have run into a possibly related problem that I cant seem to figure out on my own.

I have uploaded my app to a test repo [here](https://github.com/Torgian/testEngApp)on Github. Please download and run it.

My problem lies in the Class page which is controlled through the lesson files in the app folder.

If you take a look at the lesson html page, you can see I am trying to show the student image and name, as well as the lesson content below that. I'm currently trying to use @Pardeep Jain's suggestion on how to iterate through multi-dimensional arrays.

I'm not sure if I'm getting the syntax right. However, during my attempt to figure this out, I ran into the problem of the student name and images not loading. Because of this, I think I may be missing something in my app that I am overlooking.

Please assist and help me figure out this problem. Thank you.

Comment: The chances that anybody downloads code are quite low. A Plunker might be suitable. The code that is related to the core of the problem should be included directly in your question above.

Comment: Unfortunately it is vastly easier for anyone to download the code and run it than trying to set up a plunker for this particular problem, partly because I would have to write almost the entire app in plunker, and writing the code in here would not give the tester a good idea of what i have.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem. It ended up being a promise that I had written in the lesson.service.ts file and it was interfering with a similar promise. After deleting it, it's not posting to the page.

I still have to figure out how to read multi-dimentional arrays, but I'm glad I was able to figure this bug out on my own.

Deleted repository.